# javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection vs org.apache.http.client.HttpClient

Tags: java, http, httpclient, httpsurlconnection

I'm trying to get response info from apache *httpClient*, but I'm not getting the information I need. *HttpsURLConnection* gave me some problems in the past and I don't want to use it. I¡m trying to get help from someone who knows deeply these libraries and offers me the cause or the solution.

When I tryed to call URL with *HttpsURLConnection* it offers me all "document" url calls and I can iterate over all...

```
public InputStream getResource(String resource, String username, String password) throws Exception {
        int redirects = 0;

        // Place an upper limit on the number of redirects we will follow
        while (redirects < 10) {
            ++redirects;

            // Configure a connection to the resource server and submit the request for our resource.
            URL url = new URL(resource);
            HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
            if (url.getProtocol().equalsIgnoreCase("https")) {
                connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            } else {
                connection = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL("https", url.getAuthority(), url.getFile()).openConnection();
            }
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setDoInput(true);

            // If this is the URS server, add in the authentication header.
            if (resource.startsWith(URS)) {
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization",
                        "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes()));
            }

            if (connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                return connection.getInputStream();
            }

            if (connection.getResponseCode() != 302) {
                throw new Exception("Invalid response from server - status " + connection.getResponseCode());
            }
            
            resource = connection.getHeaderField("Location");
        }
        
        throw new Exception("Redirection limit exceeded");
    }
```

... with this code, I can iterate over each url and I can send basic auth and then login in the page. After it, I then call other time and get its info...

[image]

With *HttpsURLConnection* I'm getting this 2 documennts, and I just read the "location" of the first one. Then I recall with the basic auth.

If I try to do the same with org.apache.http.client.HttpClient ...

```
public Optional<HttpPayloadResponse> getResource(String resource, String username, String password) throws Exception {
        int redirects = 0;

        // Place an upper limit on the number of redirects we will follow
        while (redirects < 10) {
            ++redirects;
            
            BasicHttpQuery basicHttpQuery = new BasicHttpQuery();
            basicHttpQuery.setTimeOutMillis(20000);
            basicHttpQuery.setHttpRequestType(HttpRequestTypeEnum.GET);
            basicHttpQuery.setUrl(resource);
            basicHttpQuery.setTimeOutMillis(30000);
            
            Optional<HttpPayloadResponse> response = EoHttpClient.executeHttpQuery(basicHttpQuery);
            
            if (response.get().getResponseHeaders().get("Location").equals(URL_FILE_2_DOWNLOAD)) {
                return response;
            } else {
                // If this is the URS server, add in the authentication header.
                if (resource.startsWith(URS)) {
                    basicHttpQuery.getHttpHeader().put("Authorization", 
                            "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes()));
                }
                
                resource = response.get().getResponseHeaders().get("Location");
            }
        }
        
        throw new Exception("Redirection limit exceeded");
    }
```

---

```
try(CloseableHttpClient httpClient = buildHttpClientNotCheckSsl(archiveQuery.getTimeOutMillis())) {
        
        HttpRequestBase httpOperation = null;
        if (archiveQuery.getHttpRequestType().equals(HttpRequestTypeEnum.GET)) {
            httpOperation = new HttpGet(archiveQuery.getUrl());
        } else {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(archiveQuery.getUrl());
            httpPost.setEntity( new StringEntity(archiveQuery.getQueryPayload()));
            httpOperation = httpPost;
        }
        
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> currentHeader : archiveQuery.getHttpHeader().entrySet()) {
            httpOperation.setHeader(currentHeader.getKey(), currentHeader.getValue());
        }
        
        try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpOperation)) {

public static CloseableHttpClient buildHttpClientNotCheckSsl(int timeoutMillis) throws Exception {
     
    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().
            setConnectTimeout(timeoutMillis).setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeoutMillis).setSocketTimeout(timeoutMillis).
            build();

    final SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
            .loadTrustMaterial(null, (x509CertChain, authType) -> true)
            .build();

    return HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setSSLContext(sslContext)
            .setConnectionManager(
                    new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(
                            RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                            .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.INSTANCE)
                            .register("https", new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext,NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE))
                            .build()
                            ))
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
            .build();
}
```

It only gave me the second call, It didn't show me all "documents" call I see in the network dev explorer from navigator. Why? Is there a way to do with apache httpClient?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It is needed to disable redirect in the call...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://cddis.nasa.gov/archive/products/iers/finals2000A.data");

    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().disableRedirectHandling().build();
         CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request)) {

        // Get HttpResponse Status
        System.out.println(response.getProtocolVersion());              // HTTP/1.1
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());   // 301
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase()); // Moved Permanently
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().toString());        // HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            // return it as a String
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            System.out.println(result);
        }

    }

}
```